# javascript combine two with IF

Tags: if-statement

I am trying to combine two javascripts to one using IF.

I want IF script1 is True to run only script1. 
And IF script1 is False to run script2.

Script1= Check all field with "required" if empty in a contact form.
Script2= Send email using ajax.

**Script1**

```
  $('document').ready(function () {
    $('form#contact-form').submit(function(e) {

        var ref = $(this).find("[required]");

        $(ref).each(function(){
            if ( $(this).val() == '' )
            {
                alert("Required field should not be blank.");

                $(this).focus();

                e.preventDefault();
                return false;
            }
        });  return true;
    });
});
```

**Script2**

```
   $('document').ready(function () {
    $('form#contact-form').submit(function () {
        var form = $(this);
        var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
        $('#loader').html('<img src="../spinner.gif" /> Please Wait...');

        form.fadeOut(500, function () {
            form.html("<h3>Thank you.").fadeIn();
            $('#loader').html('');
        });

        // Normally would use this
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'process.php', // Your form script
            data: post_data,
            success: function(msg) {
                form.fadeOut(500, function(){
                    form.html(msg).fadeIn();
                });
            }
        });

        return false;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This script should work for you.

```
$('document').ready(function() {
 $('form#contact-form').submit(function (e) {
  var valid = true;
  var ref = $(this).find("[required]");
  $(ref).each(function(){
    if ($(this).val() == '' )
    {
      alert("Required field should not be blank.");
      $(this).focus();
      e.preventDefault();
      valid = false;
      return false;
    }
  });

  if (valid){
    var form = $(this);
    var post_data = form.serialize(); //Serialized the form data for process.php
    $('#loader').html('<img src="../spinner.gif" /> Please Wait...');

    form.fadeOut(500, function () {
      form.html("<h3>Thank you.").fadeIn();
      $('#loader').html('');
    });

    // Normally would use this
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'process.php', // Your form script
      data: post_data,
      success: function(msg) {
        form.fadeOut(500, function(){
          form.html(msg).fadeIn();
        });
      }
    });
  }
 });
});
```

Combined both script and added/ introduced "valid" variable to validate if 'required' fields are valid.

Comment: Thanks. It is half working. You are alert for every empty field and the php opens but refresh all page.

Comment: You're right, but the original code uses alert function to display an error.

Comment: The original code is tested and working fine. If there are any empty fields to alert(error message). The problem is that the code now alert as many times it finds an empty field. Example, there are 3 empty field, so you will get 3 times alert. In the original code you will only get 1.

Comment: You're right.  Added return statement inside an each loop, a "non-false" value will act as a continue, and return false will act as a break.

Comment: You are a genius!!! I just now show the code above. it is working. The only mistake is that the php is not showing inside the div but loading the "Thank you" message and then opens the php page.

Comment: I think the error is here " var form = $(this); " . I tested and it is not reading this form.

Comment: It looks like you are missing name attribute in <input> element.
The name attribute is used to reference elements in a JavaScript, or to reference form data after a form is submitted.

Comment: You are correct!!! Because i am trying to make this script to work, i mess up all the names. There were different input names in form and php. My last problem, is that the php is loading in the same window and not showing inside the <div> where the contact form was.

Comment: Need help, please... The "success: function(msg)" is not loading in the same window but load the message in a page. why? If you run the code only with the ajax part it is working fine. Fade out the form and fade in the msg.